# Assignment of Pandas DataFrame with float32 and float64 slow

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, floating-point

Assignments with a Pandas DataFrame with varying float32 and float64 datatypes are for some combinations rather slow the way I do it.

The code below sets up a DataFrame, makes a Numpy/Scipy computation on part of the data, sets up a a new DataFrame by copying the old one and assigns the result from the computation to the new DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

N = 1000
M = 1000

def f(dtype1, dtype2):
    coi = [str(m) for m in range(M)]
    df = pd.DataFrame([[m for m in range(M)] + ['Hello', 'World'] for n in range(N)],
                      columns=coi + ['A', 'B'], dtype=dtype1)
    Y = lfilter([1], [0.5, 0.5], df.ix[:, coi])
    Y = Y.astype(dtype2)
    new = pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True)
    print(new.iloc[0, 0].dtype)
    print(Y.dtype)
    new.ix[:, coi] = Y    # This statement is considerably slow
    print(new.iloc[0, 0].dtype)


from time import time

dtypes = [np.float32, np.float64]
for dtype1 in dtypes:
    for dtype2 in dtypes:
        print('-' * 10)
        start_time = time()
        f(dtype1, dtype2)
        print(time() - start_time)
```

The timing result is:

```
----------
float32
float32
float64
10.1998147964
----------
float32
float64
float64
10.2371120453
----------
float64
float32
float64
0.864870071411
----------
float64
float64
float64
0.866265058517
```

Here the critical line is `new.ix[:, coi] = Y`: It is ten times as  slow for some combinations.

I can understand that there needs to be some overhead for reallocation when there is a float32 DataFrame and it is assigned a float64. But why is the overhead so dramatic.

Furthermore, the combination of float32 and float32 assignment is also slow and the result is float64, which also bothers me.

Comment: This may be related to the coercing. See this follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230388/why-does-pandas-coerce-my-numpy-float32-to-float64?lq=1

Comment: I have added an issue a Pandas GitHub: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12255

Answer (score 0):

Single-column assignments does not change type and iterating with a for-loop over columns seems reasonably fast for non-type-casting assignments, - both float32 and float64. For assignments involving type casting the performance is usually twice as bad as the worst performance for multiple column assignment

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

N = 1000
M = 1000

def f(dtype1, dtype2):
    coi = [str(m) for m in range(M)]
    df = pd.DataFrame([[m for m in range(M)] + ['Hello', 'World'] for n in range(N)],
                      columns=coi + ['A', 'B'], dtype=dtype1)
    Y = lfilter([1], [0.5, 0.5], df.ix[:, coi])
    Y = Y.astype(dtype2)
    new = df.copy()
    print(new.iloc[0, 0].dtype)
    print(Y.dtype)
    for n, column in enumerate(coi):  # For-loop over columns new!
        new.ix[:, column] = Y[:, n]
    print(new.iloc[0, 0].dtype)

from time import time

dtypes = [np.float32, np.float64]
for dtype1 in dtypes:
    for dtype2 in dtypes:
        print('-' * 10)
        start_time = time()
        f(dtype1, dtype2)
        print(time() - start_time)
```

The result is:

```
----------
float32
float32
float32
0.809890985489
----------
float32
float64
float64
21.4767119884
----------
float64
float32
float32
20.5611870289
----------
float64
float64
float64
0.765362977982
```